# Yazidi language support in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language

On my computer, with Windows 10, from the web browsers (Firefox, Chrome) I can view sites in various languages that have an alphabet different from the Latin one (Chinese, Japanese, Central Kurdish/Sorani, etc.) and the characters are displayed correctly; Also, the characters from these non-Latin languages are displayed correctly in various text editors: notepad, editplus, etc. although these languages are not installed in Settings/Time & language/Language!

However, for some languages, the characters are not displayed correctly (only squares are displayed): For example, Yazidi.

What should I do so that the characters from the Yazidi alphabet are also displayed correctly?

From Windows/Settings/Languages I can't install support for the Yazidi language because it doesn't exist in that list!

But normally I don't have to install this language from the settings, because I didn't install the other languages (Chinese, Japanese) from there, and yet their characters are displayed correctly.

I did not find the answer to this question on the Microsoft website.

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple languages, [Kurmanji, کورمانجی, and North Mesopotamian Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yazidis) are used by Yazidis, and [Ezdiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezdiki) is considered the national language, you might need to install the appropriate font. You might try [FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/language/kurdish_kurmanji), though *many* fonts support Kurmanji, so I'm not sure why there's an issue.